# SugarCRM/SuiteCRM how to separate one relation from flex relate field

Tags: php, sugarcrm, suitecrm

i.e. I want to have additional field 'Accounts' in 'Tasks' Edit View.

Is there a way to separate 'Account' from 'Related To'?

I would rather not adding another 1-n relation Accounts-Tasks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to remove 'Accounts' from the list of modules showed in the vardefs by setting a custom list to the 'options' setting in where you have removed accounts. Also check this which how to add a module to the list http://developer.sugarcrm.com/2011/05/16/howto-create-a-flex-relate-for-other-modules/